# Chromatic Numbers for Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Find the chromatic numbers of the following graphs:

1. a graph $G_1$ obtained from $K_n$ by removing one edge
2. a graph $G_2$ obtained from $K_n$ by removing two edges *with* a common vertex
3. a graph $G_3$ obtained from $K_n$ by removing two edges *without* a common
   vertex.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: It seems like you have given this some thought.  Have you been able to narrow the chromatic number down to a certain range?  For instance, can you show that $G_1$ can be $(n-1)$-coloured, or that it can't be, say, $(n-3)$-coloured?  Please share more details.

Comment: I know that K_n can be n-colored, but have been struggling to prove much beyond that.

Comment: Actually, K_n-1 is a part of G_1, so it can be n-1 colored, and that's a lower bound. It's obvious that an n-1 coloring exist, as we take the n-coloring of K_n and color the two vertices that shared that edge the same. So for G_1 the answer is n-1

Comment: On the same note, $G_2$ is a part of $G_1$ and $K_{n-1}$ is a part of $G_2$ (remove the shared vertex). Thus, it should also have chromatic number n-1

Comment: @tijme Very nicely done!  Any thoughts about $G_3$?  Seems like it might be hard to find $K_{n-1}$ in it, but can we find a copy of $K_{n-2}$?  Can we find an $(n-2)$-colouring to match?

Comment: We can find the copy of $K_{n-2}$ easily (take a vertex from each edge). We can find an n-2 coloring for $G_3$ from $G_1$ the same way we found one for $G_1$ from $K_n$

Comment: @tijme You're welcome.  You did most of the work anyway :).

Answer (score 4):

1. $K_n-1$ is a part of $G_1$, so it can be $n-1$ colored, and that's a lower bound. It's obvious that an $n-1$ coloring exist, as we take the n-coloring of $K_n$ and color the two vertices that shared that edge the same. So for $G_1$ the answer is $n-1$
2. $G_2$ is a part of $G_1$ and $K_{n−1}$ is a part of $G_2$ (remove the shared vertex). Thus, it should also have chromatic number $n-1$
3. $G_3$ contains $K_{n−2}$ (take a vertex from each edge). We can find an $n-2$ coloring for $G_3$ from $G_1$ the same way we found one for $G_1$ from $K_n$